# Стилизация Baloons YandexMaps API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Необходимо поставить overflow-y:hidden и изменить height

```
<ymaps id="id_152182549317635913606" class="" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; height: 400px; width: 307px; display: block;">
```

[image]

Не подскажете как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/balloonoptions-docpage/#style
Документация по balloon, в поле style можно подставить нужные стили.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ymap-marker :balloon-template="balloonTemplate" />

computed: {
            balloonTemplate() {
                return `
                    <div class='body_balloon'>
                        ...
                    </div>
                `
            }
        }
```

Далее стили на класс обычным CSS